# Prove Equal Matrices and Matrix-Vector Products for a Linearly Independent Spanning Set

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove: Suppose that *$C$* = {$u_1,u_2,\dots,u_p$} is a linearly independent spanning set for $\mathbb{C}^n$. Suppose also that $A$ and $B$ are $m$ x $n$ matrices such that *$Au_i$* = *$Bu_i$* for every $1 \le i \le n$. Then $A = B$.

---

By definition we know that $Au = [u]_1A_1 + [u]_2A_2 + \cdots +[u]_nA_n$. Also since the spanning set $C$ is linearly independent we know that  $\alpha_1u_1+\alpha_2u_2+\cdots+\alpha_pu_p = 0$ where $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_p = 0$. I'm unsure how to use the definitions above (or maybe I'm missing a definition that I need to solve this proof) to get between $Au_i=Bu_i$ and $A=B$.

Comment: $C$ cannot be a linearly independent spanning set for $\mathbb{C}^n$ unless $p=n$.

Comment: Yeah that was one thing that I was confused about in the problem, why they didn't specify $p$ and $n$ to be equal.

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: Write down what $A=B$ really means.

Hint 2: Use the fact that $C$ is a basis and the linearity of $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $U$ be the matrix of which its $i$-th column is $u_i$. $U$ is invertible.

Since $AU=BU$, we have $(A-B)U=0$. Since $U$ is invertible, we have $A=B$.